# scroll to link id with fixed nav bar

Tags: javascript, html, css

in my web i have a fixed navigation bar and below it i have some another divs - the nav bar links connect to those links.
the problem is when i click on some link the fixed nav bar covered the begining of the div. and what i want and tring to do is that the nav bar will be at the start of the div and so it wont covered the begining. 
here is the [link](https://jsfiddle.net/jb8q53pq/) for the result.

here is my html code:

```
<body>
<div id="header">
    <div id="nav_bar">
        <ul>
            <li><a href="#">בית</a></li>
            <li><a href="#about_us">מי אנחנו</a></li>
            <li><a href="#our_services">מוצרים</a></li>
            <li><a href="#connect_us">צרו קשר</a></li>
            <li><img src="1.png"></img></li>

        </ul>
    </div>
</div>

<div id="main_pics" class="container">
<!-- photos here -->
<div id="main_photo1" class="phocont first">

</div>
<div id="main_photo2" class="phocont">

</div>
<div id="main_photo3" class="phocont">
</div>
<div id="main_photo4" class="phocont">
</div>
<div id="main_photo5" class="phocont">
</div>
</div>  
<div id="about_us" class="container">
<h1>עץ כנעני - כשעיצוב ואיכות נפגשים</h1>
<p> וייצור המוצר.</p>
<p>א.</p>


</div>

<div id="our_services" class="container">
<h1>המוצרים שלנו</h1>
</div>

<div id="connect_us" class="container">
<h1>תאמו איתנו פגישה עוד היום</h1>
</div>  

<div id="down_nav_bar" class="container">
</div>

<div id="credit" class="container">
</div>

</body>
```

here is my css code:

```
body{
background-color: white;
margin: 0px;
padding: 0px;
}
#nav_bar{
background: rgba(255,255,255,0.9);
height: 55px;
position: fixed;
width: 100%;
top: 0;
left: -2px;
z-index: 2;

}

#nav_bar ul{
padding: 0px;
text-align: center;
direction: rtl;
}

#nav_bar ul li {
display: inline-block;
padding: 0 10px;    
color: gray;
float: inherit;
font-family: "alefregular";
font-size: 23px;
}

#nav_bar ul li a{
color: inherit;
text-decoration: none;
}

#nav_bar ul li a:hover{
color:#a51212;
}

#nav_bar img{

height:18px;
position:absolute;
padding-right:20px;
top:25px;
z-index:-1px;
}
#about_us{
text-align: center;
/*height: 250px;*/
height: 100%;
font-family:"open_sans_hebrewregular", "alefregular",arial,"Times New     Roman";
color:gray;
}

#about_us p{
width: 55%;
margin: auto;
text-align: center;
direction: rtl;
padding-bottom: 10px;
line-height: 30px;

}

#our_services{
/*height: 450px;*/
text-align: center;
font-family:"open_sans_hebrewregular", "alefregular",arial,"Times New   Roman";
color: black;
background-color: rgb(224,224,224);
}
```

Comment: The issue is because navigation has fixed position. If you add top margin in all content container it will solve you issue.

Comment: but then the content begin 55px downer. that's not what i want...

Comment: You might want to use jquery and set the [.scroll()](https://api.jquery.com/scroll/) options

Comment: APRULE, please see my modified answer which better suits your needs. @gerdi, good suggestion!

Comment: it's still not working to me.

Comment: @APRULE, the fiddle is there, the last one in my answer and it is working. You need jQuery to make it work. If you want, I can convert it to pure javascript

Comment: @AmmarCSE if you dont mind i woukd like to convert it to js. thanks!

Comment: @APRULE, ok check the last fiddle in my answer for the pure javascript version

Comment: Also, make sure you change the html in the 'nav_bar' to use data-target attributes instead of href

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try adding padding top to container

```
.container
{
padding-top: 55px;
}
```

[fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/jb8q53pq/2/)

If you do not wish to have the text move down by 'x' pixels, you can programmatically scroll with an adjusted offset using jQuery:

```
$('html, body').animate({
    scrollTop: $(target).offset().top - 55
    }, 1000);
```

Notice, this example does not use `padding-top`:

[fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/jb8q53pq/4/)

Or, without jQuery:

```
window.scrollTo(0, document.getElementById(targetSection).offsetTop-55);
```

[fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/jb8q53pq/5/)

Comment: That is not what you asked ;)

Comment: i know, can u help me with the solution?

Comment: No need to involve jQuery. It's still a one-liner in vanillaJS: `window.scrollTo(0, document.getElementById(target).offsetTop-55)`

Comment: i dont get it, can you fiddle it?

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way by far would be to add some padding (as much as the navbar is high) to the divs that serve as targets for your links:

```
div.container{ padding-top: 55px; }
```

For the sake of semantics, I'd recommend you also use `section` elements instead of those meaningless `div`s, etc… https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/semantics.html#sections